# Proving the following automorphism of fields is an additive homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

I have the following question, if $ \varphi: \mathbb{F}_{p^2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p^2} $ defined as $\varphi(x) \mapsto x^p$ is an automorphism, then how do I show it is a homomorphism in the first step? (I have a problem in showing this is an additive homomorphism).

Now what I did was:

$$\varphi(a+b) = (a+b)^{p} = \binom{p}{0}a^p + \binom{p}{1}a^{p-1}b+...+\binom{p}{p-1}ab^{p-1}+\binom{p}{p}b^p$$

So now if I can show that $p^2 | \binom{p}{r}$ for all $1 \le r \le p-1$ then I will obtain that $\varphi(a+b) = a^p+b^p =\varphi (a)+\varphi(b).$ 
But how do I show the above claim?

I read about a Kummer's version of Lucas theorem on the internet, but I don't get how to use that? Is that needed to prove the above claim or something else?

Any hints? Also, I cannot find a duplicate if one exists, then please point out. Thanks.

Comment: It suffices to show that $p\mid\binom n r$ for all $r$ in that range. This is because $px=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$. Are you familiar with the concept of *the characteristic of a field*? Particularly that it is always a prime number (or zero).

Comment: yeah, thanks!! I always miss the important details. My bad.

Comment: Do you know how to construct $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ for example when $p=3$

Comment: yeah!! I know that and also for $F_q$ for $q= {p^k}, p$ prime .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false that $p^2 | \binom{p}{r}$ for *any* $r$, but this is unnecessary, since $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ has characteristic $p$, not $p^2$.

That is, all you need is that $p | \binom{p}{r}$ for $1 \leq r \leq p-1$, which is true.